# Using POST to send JSON object Asynchronously (android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException)

Tags: java, android, post

I am trying to send JSON using the http POST method to a web service. Additionally I am trying to make it asynchronous so it runs in a background thread on the android device.

My problem is:

I want to make this class generic so I can send any JSON object. I added another parameter to sendHTTPData(String url, JSONObject json). In order for this to run in a background thread I must explicitly override doInBackground.

If I explicitly override doInBackground, how do I pass my JSON object in to this generic method.

When I do run sendHTTPData on its own I get android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException.

Code:

```
    public class SendHttpDataAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void,  String> {
    private static final String TAG = "SendHttpDataAsync";

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        return sendHTTPData(urls[0], MY_JSON_OBJECT);
    }

    public String sendHTTPData(String url, JSONObject json) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            URL object=new URL(url);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) object.openConnection();

            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

            OutputStreamWriter streamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());

            streamWriter.write(json.toString());
            streamWriter.flush();

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);

                String response = null;
                while ((response = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {  
                    stringBuilder.append(response + "\n");  
                }  
                bufferedReader.close();  

                Log.d(TAG, stringBuilder.toString());
                return stringBuilder.toString();
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, connection.getResponseMessage());
                return null;
            }   
        } catch (Exception exception){
            Log.e(TAG, exception.toString());
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (connection != null){
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you're not running anything in the `doInBackground()` method, and this is the only one method that is *not* called on the main `UI` `Thread`. That means that you have to call your network method inside `doInBackground()`, otherwise you'll get that `NetworkOnMainException`.

**---- EDIT ----**

To pass some parameters to the `AsyncTask`, do the following:

1. Replace `AsyncTask<String, Void,  String>` with `AsyncTask<JSONObject, Void, String>`. This way, you're saying that the parameter you'll get in `doInBackground()` is a `JSONObject`.
2. Now your `doInBackground()` method would have this parameter: `doInBackground(JSONObject... params)`
3. Get the parameter you're passing to the method this way:

   ```
   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(JSONObject... params) {
     JSONObject myJsonObject = params[0];
     sendHTTPData(url, myJsonObject);
   }
   ```
4. Now just call your `AsyncTask` this way:

   ```
   SendHttpDataAsync at = new SendHttpDataAsync();
   at.execute(myJsonObject);
   ```

Comment: Yes I realise there is no code in it which is why I ran sendHTTPData on its own.

If I could run it in doInBackground, how would I pass my JSONObject to it?

Comment: The string was there so I could pass in the url for the POST, now with the above I will only be able to pass in the json object? new SendHTTPDataAsync().execute("http://.....");

Comment: Unfortunately, you can pass in just one class of parameter. If you have 2 different params, create a wrapper class that would contain both, create an object, set the url and the JSONObject, and process it the same way I did (but with the wrapper class).